# Installed Ubuntu software is not showing

Tags: startup-applications, intel-nuc, core-apps

I installed Ubuntu on my Intel i3 NUC box with optane memory and 1TB regular hard disk. Provided 50GB space for Ubuntu and installed. After the installing progress bar finished, it asked me to restart the computer. The screen turned blank except for the blinking underscore. I waited for a considerable time, but since nothing happened, I switched off the machine, removed the bootable USB, changed BIOS for regular booting from hard disk. Finally, the pink screen with choice for selecting the OS (Windows 10 or Ubuntu) appeared. I selected Ubuntu for booting, and it opened without any error, but the applications folder is not showing installed software.

Comment: What application folder ?

Comment: What applications did you install? Please give us examples. - And did you install them while running the live system, that you used to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can find installed software in many ways, two of them would be:

from a terminal press CTRL+ALT+T to show one and write `dpkg -l | less`

from the GUI press `ALT+F2` and write `software-center` then go to installed tab

Sorry not sure what you want to mean with "applications folder"